# Akénéo service pim_catalog.saver.product is private and can't be used in my bundle's Controller

Tags: symfony, symfony4, akeneo

According to the docs, https://docs.akeneo.com/4.0/manipulate_pim_data/product/save.html, I should be able to call `$saver = $this->get('pim_catalog.saver.product');` in my bundle's controller, like this:

```
<?php
namespace XXX\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ExportController extends Controller
{
    public function exportProduct($id): Response
    {
        $saver = $this->get('pim_catalog.saver.product');
        $saver->save($id);

    
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>foo</body></html>'
        );
    }

}
```

However I get this error:

> [2020-11-05 13:44:58] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "The "pim_catalog.saver.product" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead." at /var/www/html/pim/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php line 275 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException(code: 0): The "pim_catalog.saver.product" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead. at /var/www/html/pim/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:275)"} []

So I would want to override the declaration of this service by adding a `services.YML` file into my bundle's configuration directory (`mybundle/Resources/config/services.YML`) :

```
services:
  pim_catalog.saver.product:
    public: true
    priority: 999
```

However it still doesn't work.

According to the documentation of Symfony 4,  I should create an Extension class maybe. It should have the same name than Akénéo's one, but I don't find the latter.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have some hints in the error message.

> The "pim_catalog.saver.product" service or alias has been removed or
> inlined when the container was compiled. You should either **make it
> public**, or **stop using the container directly and use dependency
> injection instead**

As a best practice, I would discourage making it public since you are not the service provider and there is a better and easier way to solve your issue. So you are left with the second option which is the way to go in my humble opinion.

I don't know specifically about Akeneo but I do know about Symfony and dependency injection. So I would suggest using the argument typehint in your controller méthod.

**1. Check the autowiring class/interface to use for service** 'pim_catalog.saver.product'

List all defined autowiring and look for the one mentioning 'pim_catalog.saver.product'

```
console debug:autowiring
```

OR just check for all autowired class/interface with akeneo in the name (this is likely)

```
console debug:autowiring akeneo
```

**2. Update your controller code to add the type-hinted argument**

Something in the lines of the following

```php
<?php
namespace XXX\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// I just picked that interface after looking it up in Akeneo documentation
// But there is another one that can be used if you want to save multiple
// products, so beware.
use Akeneo\Tool\Component\StorageUtils\Saver\SaverInterface;

class ExportController extends Controller
{
    public function exportProduct($id, SaverInterface $saver): Response
    {
        $saver->save($id);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>foo</body></html>'
        );
    }

}
```

The process is documented here https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller.html#fetching-services

**3. (Hopefully) Enjoy a working code !**

;-)

Comment: Thank you! The first step shows no result however, letting me think that there isn't any autowiring class/interface to use. So are you sure `SaverInterface` will work in the controller? I tried it and got the exception "thecontroller requires that you provide a value for the "$saver" argument."

Comment: So the message "thecontroller requires that you provide a value for the "$saver" argument." just means that you didn't activate autowiring for your controller arguments. For this, you need to tag your controller with the tag 'controller.service_arguments''. 
You can even activate the tag globally for all YOUR controllers in a folder with thie piece of (yaml) config :

  Namespace\Of\You\Controller\:
    resource: 'sub/path/to/controller/dir'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

Comment: `controller.service_arguments` is not Symfony 4 nope?^^ and thank you again :) Edit: now i have this error, letting me think that this interface actually doesn't exist: ""it references interface "Akeneo\Tool\Component\StorageUtils\Saver\SaverInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to one of these existing services:

Comment: So I think there isn't any ` pim_catalog.saver.produc` autowired interface/class :-(